# Confidence Interval where standard divination is not given

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, confidence-interval

> A transport company carries out a survey to gauge reaction to a
>   proposed train timetable change. The survey finds that 122 out of a
>   sample of 200 randomly selected passengers react positively to the new
>   timetable. Infer a 95% confidence interval for the proportion of the
>   train passenger population concerned who can be expected to react
>   positively to the proposed timetable change.

I am confused as the SD is not given I know the formula to get calculate the answer but I am not sure if I am right

> As e survey finds that 122 out of a sample of 200

Should I state **N** = 122?

The way I went about this question is using the formula but it is completely off as I am getting strange results

[image]

**N** = 200

**P** = 122/200 = .61

**Interval at 95%** = 1.96

√((.61)(1-.61)

= √((.61)(39)/200

= 0.0024 * 1.96

= 0.004

Comment: Look at the question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1716855/
The confidence interval for success probability of Bernoulli distribution is described there.

Comment: Confidence interval will be 
$$
\left(\frac{122}{200}-1{.}96 \sqrt{\frac{\frac{122}{200}\left(1-\frac{122}{200}\right)}{200}},\;\frac{122}{200}+1{.}96 \sqrt{\frac{\frac{122}{200}\left(1-\frac{122}{200}\right)}{200}}\right) = (0.61-1.96\cdot 0.0345,\,0.61+1.96\cdot 0.0345).
$$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).